# Coroutines Get Request

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I cannot figure out how to make asynchronous Get requests correctly. I have a coroutine with get request. It returns me the room ID that I need when I record a player, but the problem is that all this is done in one function, when creating a room and because of this, the coroutine does not have time to write data. Then this Get request is used in real time to get the necessary IDs that change and the same problem is there.
My Get request:

```
    IEnumerator GetRequest(string uri)
    {
        using (UnityWebRequest webRequest = UnityWebRequest.Get(Host + uri))
        {
            yield return webRequest.SendWebRequest();
            response = webRequest.downloadHandler.text;
        }
    }
```

method:

```
    public int GetID(string entity, string identify, string ID)
    {
        StartCoroutine(GetRequest(entity + identify));
        var json = ParseJson(response);
        return int.Parse(json[ID]);
    }
```

And where i call him

```
    public void CreateRoom()
    {
        TypedLobby sqlLobby = new TypedLobby("myLobby", LobbyType.SqlLobby);
        string sqlLobbyFilter = "C0";
        SetNickName(userName.text);
        RoomOptions roomOptions = new RoomOptions
        {
            MaxPlayers = 5,
            CustomRoomProperties = new ExitGames.Client.Photon.Hashtable() { { sqlLobbyFilter, "0" } },
            CustomRoomPropertiesForLobby = new string[] { sqlLobbyFilter }
        };
        if (roomName.text.Length != 0)
        {
            client.PostRoom(roomName.text);
            var roomID =client.GetID("Rooms/", roomName.text, "IDRoom");
            client.PostPlayer(PhotonNetwork.NickName, roomID);
            PhotonNetwork.CreateRoom(roomName.text, roomOptions, sqlLobby);
        }
        else notice.EmptyRoomName();
    }
```

Comment: This question is about [tag:C#], not [tag:unityscript]. Also, please see [tag:visual-studio] for an explanation of when to use that tag.

Comment: To clarify the previous comment:  UnityScript is a JavaScript-like scripting language that was deprecated in 2018.  If you're using C#, you definitely aren't using UnityScript.

Comment: In short: You are not waiting for the result of the request but continue the rest of your code immediately

Comment: Please see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/405359)

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're trying to linearize a coroutine. "StartCoroutine" does not function like await.

Let's first go over how your GetRequest coroutine works.

```
IEnumerator GetRequest(string uri)
    {
        using (UnityWebRequest webRequest = UnityWebRequest.Get(Host + uri))
        {
            yield return webRequest.SendWebRequest();
            response = webRequest.downloadHandler.text;
        }
    }
```

The above code creates a new web request, and returns control back to Unity every single frame **until the web request completes.**

Think of `yield return webRequest.SendWebRequest();` like this:

```
while(!webRequest.isDone)
{
    //suspend the coroutine until next frame
    yield return null;
}
```

It's simply suspending the coroutine every frame until there's a response.

---

Now let's step through your code and see what's happening:

```
var roomID =client.GetID("Rooms/", roomName.text, "IDRoom");
```

which calls:

```
public int GetID(string entity, string identify, string ID)
    {
        StartCoroutine(GetRequest(entity + identify));
        var json = ParseJson(response);
        return int.Parse(json[ID]);
    }
```

Since *webRequest.SendWebRequest()* in your *GetRequest* method is not instant, *response* will not contain parseable JSON data until at least the next frame.

Since *GetID* is called on the frame (and is not a coroutine itself), it performs all of its logic in the frame that it's called. It attempts to *ParseJson(response)* on an unset *response*, which is why your coroutine does not have time to write.

---

How do we fix this?

There's not a one-size-fits-all solution, unfortunately. You'll need to delinearize your logic so that it can occur over multiple frames. A clever use of *Queues* could serve well here, or putting more logic inside of the CoRoutine could solve it as well.

Here's an example of using CoRoutines, since Queues would likely require more code to monitor/process them:

Move your room configuration logic a coroutine (And rather than nest Coroutines, just call the webrequest from within this one):

```
public IEnumerator ConfigureRoom(string roomNameText, RoomOptions roomOptions, TypedLobby sqlLobby)
    {
        client.PostRoom(roomNameText)
        using (UnityWebRequest webRequest = UnityWebRequest.Get("Rooms/" + roomNameText))
        {
            yield return webRequest.SendWebRequest();
            response = webRequest.downloadHandler.text;
        }
        var json = ParseJson(response);
        var roomId = int.Parse(json["IDRoom"]);
        client.PostPlayer(PhotonNetwork.NickName, roomID);
        PhotonNetwork.CreateRoom(roomNameText, roomOptions, sqlLobby);
    }
```

```
//Inside of your CreateRoom() method
        if (roomName.text.Length != 0)
        {
            StartCoroutine(ConfigureRoom(roomName.text, roomOptions, sqlLobby));
        }
```

This allows your room to be created and the data to be updated all over the course of multiple frames.

**Disclaimer:** I've typed all of this in browser. There may be minor syntax errors. Please let me know so I may correct them.

Comment: Nice answer. Strong [clippy](https://i.imgur.com/qiJkgK9.jpg) energy at the beginning haha.

Answer (score 2):

Change `GetID` into a coroutine, give it an `Action` to use the `int` in, and use `yield return GetRequest(...);` instead of `StartCoroutine(GetRequest(...));`.

```
    IEnumerator GetRequest(string uri)
    {
        using (UnityWebRequest webRequest = UnityWebRequest.Get(Host + uri))
        {
            yield return webRequest.SendWebRequest();
            response = webRequest.downloadHandler.text;
        }
    }
```

method:

```
    public IEnumerator GetID(string entity, string identify, string ID, Action<int> onComplete)
    {
        yield return GetRequest(entity + identify);
        var json = ParseJson(response);
        onComplete(int.Parse(json[ID]));
    }
```

And call him

```
    public void CreateRoom()
    {
        TypedLobby sqlLobby = new TypedLobby("myLobby", LobbyType.SqlLobby);
        string sqlLobbyFilter = "C0";
        SetNickName(userName.text);
        RoomOptions roomOptions = new RoomOptions
        {
            MaxPlayers = 5,
            CustomRoomProperties = new ExitGames.Client.Photon.Hashtable() { { sqlLobbyFilter, "0" } },
            CustomRoomPropertiesForLobby = new string[] { sqlLobbyFilter }
        };
        if (roomName.text.Length != 0)
        {
            client.PostRoom(roomName.text);
            StartCoroutine(
                    client.GetID("Rooms/", roomName.text, "IDRoom", 
                        delegate(int roomID) { 
                            client.PostPlayer(PhotonNetwork.NickName, roomID);
                            PhotonNetwork.CreateRoom(roomName.text, roomOptions, sqlLobby);
                        }));
        }
        else notice.EmptyRoomName();
    }
```

Comment: I believe you would need to ```yield return StartCoroutine(GetRequest(entity + identify));``` or it won't generate a multi-frame iterator.

Comment: @ErikOverflow Oh yes, I believe you are right. Thank you.

Comment: @ErikOverflow Actually since `GetRequest` is an `IEnumerator` using `yield return GetRequest(entity + identify);` is also fine without the additional `StartCoroutine`. The difference is that this afaik would then not be individually stoppable via `StopCoroutine` (you can only stop the routine yielding it) which isn't needed in this case anyway

Comment: You appear to be correct @derHugo. Prior to 2016, Unity did not start the new coroutine automatically and I was not aware that this had been implemented in 5.4

Comment: @derHugo oh neat. I went back to that because it's a bit more aesthetic to me :)

Comment: It actually doesn't `start the new Coroutine automatically` .. what you do is extend the existing IEnumerator with additional nested `yield`s which works just the same as if you would pack it all into one single IEnumerator and use `StartCoroutine` on the most root of all nested IEnumerators. I doubt a bit that this was different before 5.4. since this is basically a pure c# thing ;)

Comment: Coroutines are native to Unity because they tie to the frame, so this is not a pure c# thing unfortunately. Prior to Unity 5.4, [you could not do this.](https://answers.unity.com/questions/724244/yield-return-m-vs-yield-return-startcoroutine.html). Unity does not that they function the same in their [StarCoroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html) docs.